# How to bind my database events into bootstrap calender control in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, events

I am new in asp.net c# am using bootstrap calendar control.
I want to use the calender control to display the Student birthday information on each day of calendar by using jQuery and Ajax. my database structure looks like

**Student name, Birth date, Description etc.**

I have accessing the Single month data to bind on calendar as per matching the Birth date and Calendar date.
but i can't able to bind it, Any help will be appreciate.

My code is

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DateTime dDate;
        if (Request["SpecificMonth"] != null)
            dDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request["SpecificMonth"]);
        else
            dDate = DateTime.Now;
        //-------------------DATABASase Events----------------
        MenuEntity ObjMenuEntity = new MenuEntity();
        ObjMenuEntity.LocationId = 2;
        ObjMenuEntity.Fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime("03-01-2015");
        ObjMenuEntity.Todate = Convert.ToDateTime("03-30-2015");
        DataSet dsBindEvent = new DataSet();
        dsBindEvent = MenuEntity.fnBindCalenderEvent(ObjMenuEntity);
        string count = dsBindEvent.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
        //--------------------Event End--------------------------
        DataTable dtEvents = new DataTable();
        dtEvents = dsBindEvent.Tables[0];
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add("Day"); //day contains day of the month
        datatable.Columns.Add("Data"); //run time produce html & just place on it.
        datatable.Columns.Add("Title");
        DataRow oRow;
        for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(dDate.Year, dDate.Month); i++)
        {
            DateTime dCalendarDay = new DateTime(dDate.Year, dDate.Month, i);
            oRow = datatable.NewRow(); // here i am preparing data for a specific day. 
            if (!bWorkingDay(dCalendarDay))
            {
                oRow["Data"] = i.ToString() + "<br/><div style='color:Olive'>" + dCalendarDay.ToString("ddd") + " " + getEvents(dCalendarDay, dtEvents);
                oRow["Title"] = "SCMC";
            }
            else
                oRow["Data"] = i.ToString() + "<br/><div style='color:Red'>" + dCalendarDay.ToString("ddd") + " " + getEvents(dCalendarDay, dtEvents);
            datatable.Rows.Add(oRow);
        }

        dlCalendar.DataSource = datatable;
        dlCalendar.DataBind();

        // here just i am making current date block. 
        if (dDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && dDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            foreach (DataListItem oItem in dlCalendar.Items)
            {
                if (oItem.ItemIndex == DateTime.Now.Day - 1)
                {
                    oItem.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                    oItem.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue; oItem.BorderWidth = 2;
                }// if closed 
            }// for closed
        }// if closed

    }
```

I have bind thats events by using another way but its not working properly

Comment: "*its not working properly*" - how is it not working?